# How to get information about groups liked by a user using Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am very new to the Graph API and a basically trying to write a python (v2.7) script which takes as input the userID of a Facebook user and returns names/IDs of all groups/pages that have been liked by the user.

I have managed to acquire an Access Token that uses the following permissions: user_likes and user_groups. Do I need anything else?

I have used the following code so far to get a JSON dump of all the output from this access token:

```
import urllib
import json
import sys
import os

accessToken = 'ACCESS_ToKEN_HERE'  #INSERT YOUR ACCESS TOKEN
userId = sys.argv[1]          
limit=100

# Read my likes as a json object
url='https://graph.facebook.com/'+userId+'/feed?access_token='+accessToken +'&limit='+str(limit)
data = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
id=0

print str(data)
```

I did get some JSON data but I couldn't find any page/group related info in it neither did it seem to be the most recently updated data! Why is this?

Also, what are the field names that must be tracked to detect a page or a group in the likes data?

Comment: How did you get this access token? Its not immortal, it expires in hours. You have to implement the login and get the access token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  are using the wrong API- `/feed` - this will fetch the feeds/posts of the user, not the pages/groups.

**To get the groups he has joined:**

API: `/{user-id}/groups`

Permissions req: `user_groups`

**To get the pages he has liked:**

API: `/{user-id}/likes`

Permissions req: `user_likes`

Comment: Thanks this worked! Just to be clear: /likes returns just all the pages that the user has liked or also all the posts/photos/updates etc.that the user has liked?

Comment: Also, is there a page where I can get a list of all the API calls and understand what each of them does?

Comment: `/likes` do not return any posts/photos likes. You can start from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/, to understand what all graph api provides you